# A video player (or solution) that allows to pause/stop viewing a video residing on a networked drive and resume on another PC from the same position?

Tags: video

Basically, what I want is this: you're watching a video e.g. on a stationary PC in your living room, then pause or stop it, go to the bedroom with your notebook, and resume viewing from exactly the same position.

I know that this is theoretically possible with Light Alloy, if you copy its preferences from one program instance to another, but I'd prefer no hassle with copying, etc. The same goes for XBMC media center: I could set up a central database for the various copies of it in my home network, but the program offers no easy way to resume viewing: one must go to the file selector, find the file you've just watched, then choose "resume" from a menu; and if you supply the file's name as a run parameter, the program starts playing it from the beginning.

I could tolerate if a player just saved the settings for each file it played in the same folder that the video was in.

Answer (score 3):

[Plex](https://plex.tv/) allows to continue watching a video from the position you stopped on another device. It can be home computer or mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that came to mind was XBMC.
[Here's a guide on how to do it on XBMC.](http://lifehacker.com/5634515/how-to-synchronize-your-xbmc-media-center-across-every-room-in-the-house)

It's a somewhat lengthy process so I won't put the full post here, but overall you'll need a MySQL Server running and configured, and then modify the `advancedsettings.xml` file in XBMC with the following contents

```
<advancedsettings>
<videodatabase>
<type>mysql</type>
<host>***.***.***.***</host>
<port>3306</port>
<user>xbmc</user>
<pass>xbmc</pass>
<name>xbmc_video</name>
</videodatabase>

<musicdatabase>
<type>mysql</type>
<host>***.***.***.***</host>
<port>3306</port>
<user>xbmc</user>
<pass>xbmc</pass>
<name>xbmc_music</name>
</musicdatabase>
</advancedsettings>
```